# How to Resolve Error with Query ImportRange

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

hoping for a little pointer in the right direction.  I'm definitely not a programmer but I'm trying to learn. :)

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1ZKw8d7OKX_LqnYx_84IHP2fuBo-6rzzZ7TuaQOfCjio","Data!A2:D7"), "select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 where Col4 != 'Completed' ", 0)
```

I'm getting an error that states:

> Error
>
> Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: Col2

There are columns 1-4 in the source sheet.  Column 4 contains status items like Completed, Waiting, New, InProgress.

What am I doing wrong? Can't figure it out for the life of me.
Also, once I have this working, is it possible to do the same thing in script, store it in an array, then email the queried data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you "Allowed Access" to the Importrange function?  Try just putting the importrange first in a different cell (any cell it doesn't matter).  If you haven't allowed access you will see #REF.  Hover/click on the cell and you will get a popup with a button titled "Allow Access".  click it, the data will appear and your query should work.

Comment: mongoose36, thank you very much.  This solved the problem perfectly.  Thanks so much!