# is there a way to force "Allow access" button popping up in google-app-script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i am working with google-app-script and use a script to fill an importrange inside a query statement into a table like this:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1xxxxxxxxxxxIDofTable";"Sheetname!A11:J1024");"select Col1,Col2 where Col6 contains 'filterterm'")
```

it seems like the allow access dialog just appears over the cell when the `IMPORTRANGE` statement is outside of the `QUERY` Statement, as also mentioned in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38689320/how-to-resolve-error-with-query-importrange).

but that seems to be only a workaround not a propper solution. Also because the problem does not appear to happen when the `IMPORTRANGE` is inside a `SORT` query like this:

```
=SORT(IMPORTRANGE("1RwI0T1tWf9XPn9WI5jrrWZ6dzheqG7u9Ry94teEQwHg";"Arbeitstabelle!A11:F1024");1;TRUE)
```

is this a bug or is there a reason for this behaviour?

And foremost:

Can I force the google-spreadsheet somehow to ask for Access permission once my script ran through?

Comment: at the moment my solution is to have a cell in the first sheet that is getting filled with a sole `IMPORTRANGE` linking to an empty cell of it self. but i am not too happy with this kind of workaround for i have to instruct everybody to then click on this cell and basically search for the "Allow access" button.

Comment: Why do you included [tag:google-drive-sdk]? Are you using it on your code or you reviewed it's documentation?

Comment: Uh. Shoot. Sry. Must have been a misspkaced click. Deleting the tag immediately.

Comment: Hi @gauguerilla Did you get it working somehoe?
Please let me know. am facing same issue.

Comment: @A_01 : sadly not. I am still using the described workaround. sorry about that. It also seems I never filed a feature request. If you do so, i would immediately rush there and vote it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question directly, I would say there is no documented way to force app script to do that. Checked [Spreadsheet App Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet) and there is no mention of it even in [Spreadsheet authorization docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization). I think this is happening because QUERY is accessing the data directly so the scripts security meausure kicked in.

Try to file a [feature request here](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Feature%20request&labels=Type-Enhancement,API-Sheets).